# Windows Phone screen lock

Tags: windows-phone-7, password-recovery

I would like to know if is a way to get screen lock's password from windows phone 7? I'm think about app which keeps passwords to later recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `API` for this for security reasons